# pattern: passing unchecked objects as ruby method default parameter

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm refactoring some code, and i found something like

**EDIT**:

Setting is a Hash stored in my database. So imagine a key-> value structured stored in a database. So if its not accessible, it will generate an exception

```
def MyClass

 def my_method(foo = Settings[:foobar]
   foo
 end

 def your_method
   my_method
 end
```

end

I don't think it safe, because, there is no checking if the Settings[:foobar] exists. My question is:

would it be safer to write it like:

```
def MyClass
   def my_method(foo)
     foo unless foo.nil?
   end
   def your_method
       my_var = Settings[:foobar] rescue "default value"
       my_method my_var
   end
end
```

and if not, any other good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If `Settings` is a hash, then `Settings[:foo]` will return `nil`. So `foo unless foo.nil?` does the same thing.

An alternative is to use the `||=` approach.

```
def method(foo)
   foo ||= Settings[:foo]
   ...
end
```

but I don't see a reason it would be any better than what you have...

```
def method(foo)
   foo ||= Settings[:foo] || "my really default default"
   ...
end
```

...except you could do something like this if there was another value you wanted to default to if your setting is missing.

Scratch that.. not thing stops you doing that anyway...

```
def method(foo = Settings[:foo])
   foo ||= "my really default default"
   ...
end
```

Hope this helped in some small way.

Comment: hi @Nigel Thorne I did update my question. The Settings, actually is a data structure stored in a database. It map to a hash, but it can generate an exception if not available.